# Относительный путь при открытии файла

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, такая проблем:
пытаюсь запустить код:

```
Image image = null;
File file = new File("tmp/assets/icon.png");
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

и получаю: `javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!`

Но при этом:

```
bufferedimage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tmp/assets/icon.png");
```

работает нормально.

Вопрос - по какой причине первый способ может не открывать файл?

P.S. Файловая структура:

```
tmp
|->assets
|   |->icon.png
|
|->FileWithPublicClass.java
```

В обоих случаях IDE говорит, что файл используется.

Comment: Замечено, что строка File file = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Full\\path\\to\\project\\TestImageIO\\src\\tmp\\assets\\icon.png"); - работает отлично, Но File file = new File("src\\tmp\\assets\\icon.png"); ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ответ:
Программа в обоих случаях работала неккоректно. Пути к файлам необходимо указывать оносительно корня проекта, а не относительно пакета, в котором используется изображение.
Т.е. в моем случае:

```
File file = new File("src/tmp/assets/icon.png");
Image image = ImageIO.read(file);
```

или

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/tmp/assets/icon.png");
```