# Как вставить картинки в JPane? Так чтобы на другом компьютере тоже отображалась картинка

Tags: java

Мне нужен способ как вставить картинку, чтобы оно отображалось на любом компьютере. А я знаю только один метод через JLable. И то он работает на одном компьютере. Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: точнее в JPanel

Comment: Опишите вашу проблему подробнее. Что значит - "как вставить картинку, чтобы оно отображалось на любом компьютере", и - "метод через JLable". Как минимум "Вставить" куда и зачем?
А так же научитесь формулировать мысль.

Comment: Прощу прощения. Я создаю приложение в Эклипс. В фрейме у меня несколько панелей. Не суть. Так вот мне нужно вставить картинку в панель. Да так, чтобы она была не локальной а отображалась на любом компьютере.

Comment: Как вариант, при загрузке картинки, можно использовать относительный путь до нее.

Comment: то есть это как?

Comment: То есть до самой папки с приложением и картинками заменить на две точки . Затем на другом компе при скачивании папки все будет окей?

Comment: думаю это ваша проблема: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416786/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: Ищите в гугле: "java относительный путь"

Answer (score 0):

если вашу картинку добавить в запускаемый jar-файл, то её потом можно загружать, как ресурс. пример:

```
new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("image.png")))
```